# modified BufferedReader to ignore last line

Tags: java

I want to use something like BufferedReader to read lines from a file but if the last line in the file does not end with a newline character, I would like it to be ignored. The standard BufferedReader will return the last line up to EOF, which is not what I want. So far, the best thing I've come up with is to copy the BufferedReader source, modify one line about handling EOFs and call it something like BufferedCompleteLineReader.. this doesn't seem very good though. Does anyone have a better idea?

The background is there are multiple readers making requests to read a file that is periodically appended with a new line of text (i.e. a log file) but each new line is only valid if it ends with a newline char. If I read the last line while it's being modified I'll get bad data. But I don't want to impose file locking because performance is more important to me than completeness (for the reader).

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just do it on the calling side, where you're reading and processing the data?

```
String nextLine = reader.readLine();
String currentLine = nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    // Use currentLine here

    // Now we'll make sure we process the line we've just read on the
    // next iteration - so long as it wasn't the last line
    currentLine = nextLine;
}
```

Comment: with that I'd never process the last line. Most of the time, I do want the last line in the file (only disregarding it if it hasn't been fully written, i.e. doesn't have an EOL char)

Comment: @David: Will the file not end with a newline when everything's been processed? And at that point don't you end up with an empty line (which you'd ignore) from BufferedReader? I can't remember offhand what its behaviour is if the last line is an empty one.

Comment: it's a lot like a log file, so it doesn't end really. New lines just keep getting appended to it. So BufferedReader is perfect for reading everything up to the last line and most of the time it's good for reading the last line, just not if the last line is currently being written and it reads a partial line.

Comment: @David: So if it may not have been finished, how will you end up reading the last line eventually? Can you provide a bit more information about this?

Comment: @Jon: sorry, I updated my original question to be clearer on this. There are multiple readers, each making multiple requests to read the file. So it's ok if some requests don't get the last line because it's still being written. After the line is written, subsequent requests will see it.

Comment: @David: So does it matter if you miss the last line, as per my code? Can you tell for sure when it's been closed for good, and read the last line then?

Comment: @Jon: it does matter in the sense that I want the last line if it's complete, which will be the case most of the time

Answer (score 2):

Subclass it and override the readLine() method to do as you want.

Comment: I thought of that initially but BufferedReader.readLine() is sufficiently complicated that I'd end up copying most of the class anyways because I do want the buffering. Also, I think adding a constraint on the subclass violates Liskov Substitution principle... that wouldn't be a deal breaker on its own but it adds to the problem.

Comment: You know you can call super.readLine() and just skip the last line?

Comment: I think that would be the same as using BufferedReader directly and ignoring the last line, wouldn't it? I do want the last line most of the time, just not if it's not terminated with a EOL character (sorry for the double-negative, I hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom subclass of FilterReader and put it between the BufferedReader and the actual file Reader/InputStream.  In your filter reader, stash a copy of the last few chars on every read(char[]) call (i say last *few* chars in case you need to handle newlines which are more than 1 char, e.g. windows).  after you read the last line, check the last chars stashed in your FilterReader to see if they represent a newline.